# Can't find CSV file in DDMS view?

Tags: java, android, file-io, ddms, opencsv

I have a CSV file I am creating with the following code:

```
        package com.tukajo.ioiograph;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.CustomLabelFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class graph_fragment extends Fragment {

    Boolean csvThreadRunning;
    private customIOIO _myIOIO;
    globalControlInstance globalData = globalControlInstance.getInstance();
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    CSVWriter writer = null;
    private Runnable mTimer1;
    private Runnable mTimer2;
    private GraphView graphView;
    private int i = 0;
    ToggleButton realTimeToggle;
    TextView graphPeakText;
    TextView graphAvgText;
    TextView graphSamplesText;
    ToggleButton csvToggler;
    private double avgSumPin39 = 0.0;
    private double avgSumPin40 = 0.0;
    private double avgSumPin41 = 0.0;
    private double avgSumPin42 = 0.0;
    private double avgSumPin43 = 0.0;

    int graphLoopCounter = 0;

    private double newValuePin39 = 0;
    private double newValuePin40 = 0;
    private double newValuePin41 = 0;
    private double newValuePin42 = 0;
    private double newValuePin43 = 0;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Fragment fragment = new graph_fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        _myIOIO = (customIOIO) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        _myIOIO.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), getActivity());
        // _myIOIO = MainActivity.get_myIOIO();
        _myIOIO.start();

        graphPeakText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphpeak);
        graphAvgText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphaverage);
        realTimeToggle = (ToggleButton) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.realtimetoggle);

        realTimeToggle
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        globalData.setLiveUpdatingEnabled(isChecked);
                        if (isChecked) {
                            updateGraphUI();
                            Log.v("PRESSED", "Button Pressed");
                        } else {
                            pauseGraphUI();
                            globalData.setGraphPeak1(0.0);
                            globalData.setGraphPeak2(0.0);
                            globalData.setGraphPeak3(0.0);
                            globalData.setGraphPeak4(0.0);
                            globalData.setGraphPeak5(0.0);
                        }

                    }
                });

        // set the initial text values for the graph peaks and the graph avgs
        graphPeakText.setText("Graph Peaks: " + globalData.getGraphPeak1()
                + " " + globalData.getGraphPeak2() + " "
                + globalData.getGraphPeak3() + " " + globalData.getGraphPeak4()
                + " " + globalData.getGraphPeak5());
        graphAvgText.setText("NOT IMPLEMENTED");

        GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(getActivity(),
                "Graph with 5 lines");

        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);
        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumVerticalLabels(8);
        graphView.addSeries(globalData.getGraphViewSeries1());
        graphView.addSeries(globalData.getGraphViewSeries2());
        graphView.addSeries(globalData.getGraphViewSeries3());
        graphView.addSeries(globalData.getGraphViewSeries4());
        graphView.addSeries(globalData.getGraphViewSeries5());
        graphView.setViewPort(0, 300);
        graphView.setScrollable(true);

        LinearLayout layoutForGraph = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.graphLayout);

        layoutForGraph.addView(graphView);

        csvToggler = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton2);
        csvToggler
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked) {
                            try {
                                csvThreadRunning = true;
                                exportToCSV();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            csvThreadRunning = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
        Log.i("Path of File = ", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator
                + "csvData"
                + File.separator + "csvDataFile.txt");
        return rootView;
    }

    public void exportToCSV() throws IOException {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator
                + "csvData"
                + File.separator + "csvDataFile.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',');
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if (csvThreadRunning) {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        try {

                            String s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                    .getLatestGraphData1()) + "pin39"; // array
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // your
                                                                        // values
                            writer.writeNext(s1);
                            s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                    .getLatestGraphData2()) + "pin40";
                            writer.writeNext(s1);
                            s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                    .getLatestGraphData3()) + "pin41";
                            writer.writeNext(s1);
                            s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                    .getLatestGraphData4()) + "pin42";
                            writer.writeNext(s1);
                            s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                    .getLatestGraphData5()) + "pin43";
                            writer.writeNext(s1);
                            writer.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    }

    public void pauseGraphUI() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer1);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer2);
    }

    public void updateGraphUI() {
        mTimer2 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                double newReadingDoublePin39 = 0.0;
                double newReadingDoublePin40 = 0.0;
                double newReadingDoublePin41 = 0.0;
                double newReadingDoublePin42 = 0.0;
                double newReadingDoublePin43 = 0.0;
                newReadingDoublePin39 = _myIOIO.getCurrentPin39Voltage();
                newReadingDoublePin40 = _myIOIO.getCurrentPin40Voltage();
                newReadingDoublePin41 = _myIOIO.getCurrentPin41Voltage();
                newReadingDoublePin42 = _myIOIO.getCurrentPin42Voltage();
                newReadingDoublePin43 = _myIOIO.getCurrentPin43Voltage();

                graphLoopCounter++;

                if (globalData.isLiveUpdatingEnabled()) {
                    globalData.setGraph2LastXValue(globalData
                            .getGraph2LastXValue() + 1d);
                    globalData.getGraphViewSeries1().appendData(
                            new TukajoData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                    newReadingDoublePin39), true, 1000);
                    globalData.getGraphViewSeries2().appendData(
                            new TukajoData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                    newReadingDoublePin40), true, 1000);
                    globalData.getGraphViewSeries3().appendData(
                            new TukajoData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                    newReadingDoublePin41), true, 1000);
                    globalData.getGraphViewSeries4().appendData(
                            new TukajoData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                    newReadingDoublePin42), true, 1000);
                    globalData.getGraphViewSeries5().appendData(
                            new TukajoData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                    newReadingDoublePin43), true, 1000);

                }
                // avgSum += newReadingDoublePin39 + newReadingDoublePin40 +
                // newReadingDoublePin41 + newReadingDoublePin42 +
                // newReadingDoublePin43;
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                Log.v("UPDATING", "Updating the graph");
                Log.v("newReadingValue", String.valueOf(newReadingDoublePin39));
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 100);
    }

}
```

However when I look under the DDMS View I do not see the file being created anywhere, any ideas why this is not appearing? I am not receiving any errors from the logcat.

Screenshot with the expected location of the file:

[image: File Locator DDMS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Log to check exact path of this file. I think that you are looking for file in wrong location.

Use:

```
     Log.I("PAth of File = ", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator
        + "csvData"
        + File.separator + "csvDataFile.txt");
```

Use above log statement in the code and check the full path of file and verify file in that path.

Comment: When I put that in either my thread or outside of it I do not get any info logcat entries at all.

Comment: Put it in your activity onCreate() method and add some logs in this method to verify that this method is get called or not. May be this method not get called from your code.

Comment: Please add your all code. So that I can verify that how you are using this functionality?

Comment: I extended the code to all of it for you to visualize.